# "*" sign alignment in android edittext

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an edit text where all character are in same orientation except " * " sign.i want to all character in same orientation. i tried font to edittext for this but it is not work. and search in the google and here but does not find any link related to my problem. but in android dialer this " * " in same orientation.
thanks in advance for help me.

Comment: can you elaborate your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common asterisk "*" sign of latin character set is displayed a bit upper, not in the middle of the text. To achieve the middle alignment you can use alternative unicode asterisk symbol like: 0x2217

My Galaxy S use the same symbol when I dial the number.

As for implementation you can just substitute the general * symbol to this 0x2217 while user entering the text.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. but i try but in the edit text field there is unicode decimal value show not the symbol.

Comment: sorry i cant vote your answer but i wish i can vote u Huuuuuuuuuuuuuuge

Comment: nice words is also an award :o)